# Excel formula - IF true, return a text and cell value

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have data across two sheets in Excel and i am trying to put together a formula in Excel that says:

*Assume i am in the cell B1 in Sheet 2*

IF the character length in Sheet 1, cell A1 is greater than 35 character
if true - return "Text:" + whatever is in the cell A1 in Sheet 1 in full length
if false - do nothing

So far i have tried:

> =IF(LEN('Sheet1'!A1)>35;"Text:"+'Sheet1'!A1)

This returns #VALUE! in the cell B1, Sheet 2. The problem is probably in combining the text and the cell value in the if_true result. Looks like a simple formula, but i can't wrap my head around this.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below-

```
=IF(LEN(Sheet1!A1)>35,"Text:" & Sheet1!A1,"")
```

Comma `(,)` and semicolon `(;)` depend on regional settings.

Comment: That's it, works great! Thanks a lot, appreciate it.